# Find "next" Timestamp in MySQL Query without using subquery

Tags: mysql, datetime, query-performance

I have a table with timestamps and some other data and I need to query not only each timestamp and associated data, but also the "next" timestamp (to use as an endpoint in my app). The following query does this correctly, but it is incredibly slow. The problem seems to be the subquery for Endstamp, because if I replace the subquery with a hardcoded value for testing, the query is reasonably fast:

```
SELECT Timestamp,USER_ID,Activity,
       (SELECT Timestamp 
        FROM timeline_db AS sub 
        WHERE (sub.USER_ID = main.USER_ID 
                AND sub.Timestamp > main.Timestamp 
                AND sub.Timestamp <= '".$epochend."'
            ) 
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS Endstamp 
FROM timeline_db AS main
WHERE (Timestamp >= '".$epochstart."' AND Timestamp <= '".$epochend."')
```

I am sure there is a less expensive way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: You have `LIMIT 1` without any kind of ordering. Are you sure that this query works?

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? It's relevant because later versions have so-called *window functions* to accelerate this sort of query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, but this is just a simplified version of my query, also it's an intranet only app and I'm literally the only user with access to begin with, so security is not an overly big concern ;)

Comment: *security is not an overly big concern.* With respect, that's what the bozos at Equifax told themselves. Cybercreeps can, and do, get into intranets and systems we all believe are safe. Cybercreeps are very smart and highly motivated.

Comment: @forpas yes, because of the way the data is imported into the table it is always in the right order, I haven't run into problems so far.

Comment: @O.Jones libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407  (I know I know, I could upgrade it though if required)

Comment: @molkemon timestamp DATATYPE has a date range ending in 2038.  By February, 2038 your app will not be able to store the date because it will be out of range.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.